# How to reference the object that name is obtaine through a paste in R

Tags: r, character, rename

I am afraid my question is pretty basic :

I create a dataframe that I name using a `paste` command as I want to have the date each time.

```
assign(paste(Fichier, Onglet2, Budget,Tour, Date,sep="_"),
       FichierExcel %>%
         read.xlsx(., sheet="DM", colNames=F, rows=(2:209)) %>%
         set_names(Colonnes_DemandeMondiale))
```

So I get a dataframe that is named `paste(Fichier, Onglet2, Budget,Tour, Date,sep="_")`, but when I try to check it by using the `headtail` function, it does only seem to see it as the string that results from the paste, not the datagframe itself.

```
> headtail((paste(Fichier, Onglet1, Budget,Tour, Date,sep="_")))
Erreur : 'x' must be a matrix or data.frame.
```

How should I specify that I want the object which name is the charater chain and not the character chain itself ?

Comment: Use `get` : `get(paste(Fichier, Onglet1, Budget,Tour, Date,sep="_"))`

Comment: @RonakShah Please no. This is almost never the correct solution when this question gets asked on here. I’m sure you know that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm I am then curious as to why this is not the correct solution, if you may elaborate (or redirect me to another post of course)

Comment: @AnthonyMartin Because for virtually all practical purposes, variable names should be treated as static, prescribed solely by the code you write; this makes the behaviour of the code exponentially easier to reason about and check. If you need dynamic names, use named vectors/lists. In fact, what your code should be doing is read XLSX sheets into *one* list of tables (or possibly into one large table), not into separate variables.