# Code readability in R : how to avoid get() and assign()

Tags: r, get, naming-conventions, assign, readability

I have read several topics in which users would advise against the use of the `get()` and `assign()` functions as it alters readibility of the code, which I cannot deny (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593520/how-to-reference-the-object-that-name-is-obtaine-through-a-paste-in-r?noredirect=1#comment112455783_63593520)).
But then I am a bit lost as to be good practice.

I have an example currently : I have a pdf with tables about several countries, which I import as a dataframe `CF_Brut_pdftools`.
My list of countries is `ListePays=c("US","JP","DE","FR","UK","IT","CA","ZE","NL","NO","ES","SE","CH")`

I have already a list of pages to use for each country. So I do

```
for (Pays in ListePays){
  assign(paste("CF",Pays,sep="_"),CF_Brut_pdftools[get(paste("Page",Pays,sep="_"))])
}
```

And the I have some data manipulation, for isntance :

```
for (Pays in ListePays2){
  assign(paste("CF",CF,"2",sep="_"),as.list(strsplit(get(paste("CF",Pays,sep="_")), "\n") [[1]]))
}
```

That will continue for several steps

What would be better options than this way ?

It is not straightforward to have a MWE in this case, but I can work on one if it helps.

Comment: Can't you skip out the first step and use `lapply` to run the function on each element of your list instead of a loop? Like `lapply(ListePays, function(x) as.list(strsplit(x, "\n") [[1]])` ?

Comment: Yes, a reproducible example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without an example, but the answer is typically to use named lists.

Let’s say you have a list of countries

```r
ListePays=c("US","JP","DE","FR","UK","IT","CA","ZE","NL","NO","ES","SE","CH")
```

And you want to store the result of `CF_Brut_pdftools(country_name)` somewhere where you can easily recover it.

The answer isn't not to create environment variable "result_US" and "result_JP".
Rather , you want to create a list called “result” where the element named "US" contains the output of `CF_Brutpdftools("US")`.

To recover the result you will simply retrieve `result[["US"]]`

How you create that list is up to you. I typically use `purrr::map()` like this:

```r
result <- purrr::map(ListePays, ~ CF_brutpdftools(.x))
```